# Itemgetter(i) for java

Tags: java, list

I recently learnt to use `ìtemgetter(i)`to get the ith element in multiple lists in python. for example:

```
j_column=list(map(itemgetter(j), board[i+1:]))
```

the `board[i+1]`part returned a list of lists, each representing a horizontal row beneath the ith row, a sub section of the board, and the code above returned the jth column of that subsection.

Now I'm doing something similar where I have to obtain the ith element of n lists, within one list. n being unknown but I have to do this in Java. I'm now looking for the equivalent of the `itemgetter(i)` function but in Java

Further info:

Assuming I had a list of lists such as: `my_list` would output `[[1,4,5,6,7],[3,0,0,9,8,4],[1,4,5]]` and the function I was looking for was called `someFunction` and I wanted the 3rd number in each sub list, meaning each element at index 2 in each sub list, this is what I'm looking for:

```
 somefunction(2, my_list); //this would output [5,0,5]
```

Comment: You need to provide some sample input and expected output if you want this question to gain any traction. I doubt there is an equivalent function in Java, but implementing this functionality is relatively straightforward...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay, thank you

Comment: I'm confused. Are you working in Python or Java?

Comment: @Kevin they are looking for Python `itemgetter` functionality in Java, I believe.

Comment: @Kevin java but I'm use to python so the examples are written in java, sorry, I don't know how best to convey it

Comment: I tried putting the example in java syntax, should look better now I hope

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: None of this is Java syntax. Most of it isn't even valid Python syntax, either.

Comment: To rephrase: you have a `List` of `List`s and you want to pick the `i`th element from each inner `List`, group them in a new `List` and return it. Correct?

Comment: @user2357112 There are only 3 code lines, the first one isn't valid cause I wanted the name to explain what I was doing, the second one was just me showing what the list looks like, and the last was my attempt at explaining what the function would do in java

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, that is what I'm trying to do, sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: I've edited the question so hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specified in your comment, you

- have a `List<List<Something>>`
- want to retrieve the `i`th element from each list, add it to a new `List<Something>` and return that list.

This code should be sufficient:

```
/**
 * Method is parameterized in the list-type, thus achieving maximal type checking. If the
 * inner lists are of different types, the inner lists must be of type List<Object>,
 * other types will not work. Type-checking is out of the window at that point.
 *
 * @param lists the list of lists, non-null and not containing null's.
 * @param i     the index to pick in each list, must be >= 0.
 * @param <T>   generic parameter of inner lists, see above.
 * @return      a List<T>, containing the picked elements.
 */
public static <T> List<T> getIthOfEach(List<List<T>> lists, int i) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

    for(List<T> list : lists) {
        try {
            result.add(list.get(i)); // get ith element, add it to the result-list
        // if some list does not have an ith element, an IndexOutOfBoundException is 
        // thrown. Catch it and continue.
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { } 
    }
    return (result);
}
```

You would call this method like so:

```
List<Integer> everyFifthInteger = getIthOfEach(listOfListsOfIntegers, 5);
List<Object>  everyFifthThing   = getIthOfEach(listOfListsOfthings, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for, sorry again for all the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

My experience with higher-order function in Java is quite limited (and frankly, it is a bit painful transitioning from Python) but this mimics `itemgetter` in Python, although it only accepts a single argument whereas `itemgetter` in Python uses variable-number of argument, but you could implement that functionality yourself if you really want it (although, I'm not sure what container type should be returned, Python uses tuples, I don't know what a good substitute would be in Java):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Main {
  public static <T> List<T> asList(T ... items) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T item : items) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    return list;
  }
  public static <T> Function<List<T>, T> itemgetter(int i){
    Function<List<T>, T> f = l -> l.get(i);
    return f;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> myList = asList(
        asList(1,4,5,6,7),
        asList(3,0,0,9,8,4),
        asList(1,4,5)
      );
    List newList = myList.stream()
                          .map(itemgetter(2))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(newList);

  }
}
```

And the output:

```
[5, 0, 5]
```

Comment: Remark: [`Arrays.asList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) does what your `asList(...)` does =). Question: What happens if you `itemgetter(myList, 3);`?

Comment: Oh and you have a minor typo here: `.map(itemgetter(2))` (the `2` looks like it should be an `i`).

Comment: @Turing85 WHOOPS sorry, pasted wrong portion of my code

Comment: @Turing85 yes, sorry, I was using an online REPL and the code was a mess. I haven't really written Java in a while and getting it to compile was  pain ... really missing the type inference from Scala.

Comment: No problem. I was thinking on going down the `stream` route as well, but the problem are the possible `Exception`s. If you call your algorithm with e.g. `itemgetter(4)`, it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (as is to be expected).

Comment: @Turing85 yes, well, *it should* throw an exception, just as if you did `myArray[10]` for `int[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5}`

Comment: What would you say the time complexity of `List newList = myList.stream()
                          .map(itemgetter(2))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());` is? sorry I'm a bit of a noob at this.

Comment: @DrewU I'm not big on my Java internals, but it's basically mapping a single operation on to each item in the list, so it should be linear (well, assuming each operation is constant time). That being said, streams in Java are slower than lower-leve looping approaches, because creating a stream-object has significant overhead. In general, the more abstract you go, the less efficient it is, so `for (int i; i < n; i++)` beats `for(MyObject obj: myList)` which probably beats the equivalent stream, but in terms of time complexity, they should all be the same...

Comment: Of course, if your data is large enough, the overhead becomes trivial compared to the operation itself, and plus, there are [other advantages to streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel).